# How can I use Google's OpenID and/or OAuth services to login and allow access to APIs with only ever one prompt to the user?

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid, token

I am attempting to create a login system for my website that permits both authentication via Google's API and access to any of the OAuth-supported Google Data APIs while ideally only showing the user one prompt ever, no matter if he's creating an account or logging into his existing one. I want to minimize the number of times he's asked for approval.

I am aware that Google provides Hybrid OpenID/OAuth for this purpose, but the issue is that *every time I add OAuth extensions to my OpenID request, it never remembers the user's approval for that request*. Is there *any* way for the approval to be remembered when I am doing Hybrid OpenID/OAuth? If I just do OpenID without OAuth extensions, everything is remembered just fine and it doesn't keep bugging the user with the prompt.

Here are the pertinent extensions I'm sending in addition to my OpenID request, which result in me getting an OAuth request token (good) but cause the approval to never get remembered (bad).

PHP syntax:

```
$args["openid.ns.ext2"] = 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0';
$args["openid.ext2.consumer"] = 'www.MYSITE.com';
$args["openid.ext2.scope"] = 'http://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/';
$args["openid.mode"] = 'checkid_setup';
$args["openid.realm"] = 'http://www.MYSITE.com/';
```

Is it normal for Hybrid OpenID/OAuth to act this way (not remembering the last OAuth authorization)? What is the best way to get around this? I have thought of storing cookies on the user's computer to link to somewhere in my database so I could use the last access token again, etc... (the issue here being I don't know whose token to look up unless I know who the user is...a circular problem). And doing an OpenID-only request to get his user ID to see if he has an account in order to look up his access token, followed by an OpenID+OAuth request (if an access token for him isn't stored) would result in two prompts, which really wouldn't help.

It also seems like Hybrid only supports OAuth 1.0, which I think is fine until 2015, so it's not an issue right now for me. I am assuming they will support OAuth 2.0 in the future.

Is **checkid_immediate** relevant to this in any way? I'm just not sure how to use this to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using OAuth 2.0.  This supports getting both identity and access to APIs -- so accomplishes the same end goal, but is much easier than OAuth 1 Hybrid.

Take a look here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

The scopes you're trying to access are included in the URL (see "Forming the URL").  The referenced doc lists the scopes required for getting identity/profile information.  You can simply add additional scopes to the string, comma-delimited in order to request access to other APIs.  The resulting access token will access both the APIs and identity information (via the UserInfo API endpoint mentioned).

That said, what you're trying to do with OpenID 2.0/OAuth 1 hybrid should work-- and the user should see a checkbox for "remembering" the authorization.  If you really want to debug this further, it'd be helpful to have a webpage you can point to which kicks off this authentication+authorization flow so we can see what's happening.

Comment: Thank you! With OAuth 2.0, I haven't so far found out how to identify whether the user has an active session with Google or not and if he does, what his active session id (a "claimed_id" or unique Google id) is, without ever showing him anything. This is necessary because I need to see if he has an active account with us when he goes to log in, and if he does, to ensure his account doesn't get "re-created" in our database every time he logs in. I still want to store data related to his account locally somehow on my database server. (character limit..I'll have to comment twice.)

Comment: And I have seen that page, and have implemented some aspects of OAuth 2.0 (I guess just API access) into my site, but I have some concerns about this.

It seems like identity and API authorization can't be done "concurrently to the user" (one prompt total) with OAuth 2.0, which I'm assuming was the whole motive for the Hybrid approach, or am I wrong? I have read through almost every page on Google's Dev docs and I'm still confused because I don't have practical experience with this.

Comment: Yes, you can get access to both identity and additional information (such as YouTube videos, contacts, Google Drive) in 1 prompt in the user's lifetime.  You simply specify the multiple scopes you need.

The user will be prompted the first time you request access to their info, and only the first time.  Of course, you won't get their unique Google ID until after they've approved the request the first-time.  But on subsequent requests, it'll be a redirect to Google, then an immediate redirect back to your app with either an authorization code or an access token (depending on flow you choose).

Comment: Note: If you need long-term offline access to a user's data (say to synchronize their user Contacts even when they're not actively using your app), you can specify response_type=code when you redirect to Google. The *very* first time the user approves this request, you'll get an authorization code which you can then exchange for both an access token and a refresh token.  You store this refresh token in your DB, and use this for access to the Contacts API.  

On subsequent logins, you redirect the user to Google, get a code, exchange it for access token, and get user's ID to log them in.

Comment: Thank you! I have been able to figure everything out with OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that checkid_immediate (and x-has-session, not sure if that's needed or even working) is allowing me to determine whether or not a user is logged in without prompting him, and if he is, it is giving me a claimed_id by which I can identify the user. That's exactly what I needed. The original question is solved, *but* I do want to figure out how to use identify with OAuth 2.0 because I have already implemented that.

Furthermore, I've noticed that when using OpenID/OAuth that the user still gets asked to authorize OAuth even after he's authorized OpenID. I can't see the advantage to the hybrid approach from the user's perspective.

If the user is logged out of Google, that's a total of three prompts just to sign up for my website and grab his name and profile image.

Comment: oops. I forgot that the Oauth request token from OpenId was already authorized. maybe it will help to do OAuthGetAccessToken immediately after Hybrid instead of OAuthAuthorizeToken. I'm trying it...

Comment: I was successful in using OAuthGetAccessToken to get an access token after my Hybrid OAuth dance, omitting the 'oauth_verifier' parameter (irrelevant to Hybrid).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wondered, here are the steps necessary to get Hybrid OpenID/OAuth completely working (an overview). I was confused thoroughly throughout this process, so I hope this helps someone.

- Do normal OpenID handshake and add on AX extensions for OAuth 1.0.

  - Use 'checkid_immediate' to permit probing for an active Google session *without* prompting the user. Use *claimed_id* as a unique identifier to link the user to your database.
  - If 'setup_needed' is returned, use 'checkid_setup' so the user is prompted and verified before continuing.
  - This leaves you with two possibilities. *checkid_immediate* returning immediately giving you a claimed_id, or a claimed_id coming through after *checkid_setup* (basically sign-up) succeeds.
- Hybrid OpenID/OAuth 1.0 will give you an *authorized* request token.
- Use the *authorized* request token to get an *access token* (you *only* need to call OAuthGetAccessToken)
- Use that OAuth 1.0 access token to do whatever you want.

I was successful in using OAuthGetAccessToken to get an access token from the authorized request token my Hybrid OAuth dance, omitting the 'oauth_verifier' parameter (irrelevant to Hybrid).

I was successful in using OAuthGetAccessToken to get an access token after my Hybrid OAuth dance, omitting the 'oauth_verifier' parameter (irrelevant to Hybrid).

In a PHP/Zend environment:

```
$config = array(
    'accessTokenUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken',
    'consumerKey' => $consumer_key,
    'consumerSecret' => $consumer_secret
);
$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($config);

$zendRToken = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Request(); // create class from request token we already have
$zendRToken->setToken($requestToken);

try{
    $accessToken = $consumer->getAccessToken(array(
          'oauth_token'               => $requestToken,
//          'oauth_verifier'            => '', // unneeded for Hybrid
          'oauth_timestamp'           => time(),
          'oauth_nonce'               => md5(microtime() . mt_rand()),
          'oauth_version'             => '1.0'
      ), $zendRToken);
} catch (Zend_Oauth_Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "OAuth Token: {$accessToken->getToken()}" . PHP_EOL;
echo "OAuth Secret: {$accessToken->getTokenSecret()}" . PHP_EOL;
```